# Android: Is it possible to insert a permanent option into custom search suggestions?

Tags: android, search

I have an Android application that has a search function that uses a ContentProvider to query the SQLite database that backs my application. As the user types in their query the application provides custom search suggestions as described by the Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html).

In addition to this I would like the search dialog to display a permanent option at the top of the custom search suggestions that when selected would perform a web search in the browser using the query (e.g., 'Search the web for *xyz*', or similar). The rest of the suggestions would be the standard search suggestions from my ContentProvider.

Is it possible to do this, and if so, how?

**Edit:**

David's suggested solution works. I did something like this:

```
MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] {BaseColumns._ID, 
      SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1});
cursor.addRow(new Object[] {0, "I'm always the top suggestion!"});
return new MergeCursor(new Cursor[] {cursor, mySearchSuggestionCursor});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be possible with the [MergeCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html), I haven't tried it myself but it looks like it was designed for this situation.

You'll have to construct your own cursor with the static data, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, David. I didn't know about MergeCursor, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Thanks, David. Your suggestion was simple, correct and saved me a lot of time!